# Import text from file to *.properties

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have a file that contains key (`public.key.pub`):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- 
   .....keykeykey....
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And I have `my-props.properties` file:

```
key1 = value1
public.key = ${file:public.key.pub}
```

But I can't import key to properties file. How to do this? What syntax?

Answer (score 0):

properties file are just key value pairs. why not just put the path and read it then in code?

Comment: I need to import text from public.key.pub file to my-props.properties file. And this text should be value of key named public.key

Comment: i think this is not possible with the normal java properties, but there is  Commons Configuration that may do the magic... https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html